# Upload & Download images or files (docs, PDF) to iOS app from device & cloud storage services

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, cloud-storage

I am developing an iOS app that has a feature attachments (images, PDF, DOC etc). The user can upload a attachment using Device Camera, Import from Photos App, Files app, or other cloud services like iCloud, Dropbox, GDrive, OneDrive etc.

The user should also be able to download the file attached by other users to his device (Either to Photos app or Files or to Cloud services).

I am aware of UIImagePickerController that helps in uploading image from Photos app or Camera. I am also aware there are individual SDK made available by each cloud service like DropBox, GDrive etc.

I can achieve this by integrating all the SDKs(those needed) but needs implementation for each provider. Moreover, here I am a bit confused with "Files" app introduced in iOS 11. Learnt that the Files app can integrate other cloud into it. I am not aware how to code to integrate Files app.

Meanwhile, I am searching if there is a library that consolidates/provides support for all cloud storages needed. Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards..

Comment: [UidocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into **UIDocumentBrowserViewController** and **UIDocumentPickerViewController**, it helps you to grab as much as information available in the device and in iCloud, you can get a callback when user tap on any doc and then you can upload it to your server. and you can also download the documents from the server and show them into the application by using **Quick Look Framework**.

**Check this link for accessing the data** : https://www.raywenderlich.com/5244-document-based-apps-tutorial-getting-started

**Check this link for presenting the document file** : https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/